# recieving broken JSON data in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, json, xml

I have PageMethod in javascript which is receiving JSON data from C#.
In C# its getting full xml data from database and converting into JSON and sending back to PageMethod.

JSON Converted data is about 33kb, but i'm not able to receive full data in javascript. I'm receiving only 9 kb of data. any solution for getting full data in java script.

```
PageMethod.methodName(onSuccess,OnFail);

function OnSuccess(result)
{
alert(result);
}
function OnFail()
{
alert("Error");
}
```

C# code as follows,

```
 ParamResult objParamResult = new ParamResult();
 objParamResult.ResultDt = string.Empty;
 DataTable XmlMainSub = objCBTag.getParamPickupDetailsDB();

 string myData = XmlMainSub.Rows[0][0].ToString();
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.LoadXml(myData);

 string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
 return jsonText;
```

Comment: Please share the c# code which is sending JSON back to client.

Comment: Try `string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(doc);`

Comment: @SiD  Not worked. still same problem persisting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- After i made lot of research, i found that its not possible to send JSON data from C# to javascript which is more than **8KB** or **9KB** in size.
- And i solved this problem by making use of c# generics which is **Dictionary** which contains *Key* and *Value* Pair. I Tried to loop XML Data which is coming from database and stored in a dictionary object.
- Then i passed it to javascript. There  i able to receive full data without any error.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
```

you can use

```
string jsonText = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(doc).toString();
```

you need to use namespace for this

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

Comment: I tried also this before but not worked for me, thanks for your reply

Comment: Oh!  'string myData' is getting  correct XML? did you check?